# Why are complex exponentials orthogonal over sums?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, fourier-series, orthogonality

Consider the following sum:

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{J-1} \omega_j^k \bar{\omega_j^l} $$

Where $\omega_j^k=\exp \left(  \frac{2\pi i j}{J} \right)$.

It is easy to show that if $k \equiv l$ modulo $J$, then the sum is $J$.

What about the case when $k$ is not $l$ modulo $J$.  The sum should be zero for this case, and computation confirms this.  I'm not sure how to go about showing this algebraically.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: geometric sequence/series

Comment: Ah, right right.  Since the modulus of the product is less than 1, I can use the geometric series partial sum equation.  Well done, thanks.

Comment: The modulus is not less than one.  However, the partial sum formula always applies.